# Programmatically monitor every IP for one URL

Tags: php, dns

Currently I monitor my websites on their IPv4 and IPv6 addresses

But my next website will be hosted with multiple IP Addresses. And I would like to ***monitor ALL of them***.

Here is my current code for dual-stack monitoring (monitoring only one IP address)

```
<?php
$resultat4 = file_get_contents_curl( 'http://www.mydomain.com/?cjg_monitoring=1', 4);
$resultat6 = file_get_contents_curl( 'http://www.mydomain.com/?cjg_monitoring=1', 6);

if (substr($resultat4,0,2) == "OK"){ echo 'IPv4 stack OK' }
if (substr($resultat6,0,2) == "OK"){ echo 'IPv6 stack OK' }

function file_get_contents_curl($url,$ip_version=0) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    if($ip_version == 4)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
    elseif($ip_version == 6)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6 );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
?>
```

How could I get all the IP addresses tested with Curl PHP ?

What I would like to do would be similar to this simpler version:

```
<?php
$ip_adds = get_all_ip_addresses( $url );

$problem_encountered = false;
foreach( $ip_adds as $ip_add ){
    $content = get_content_url_on_ip( 'http://www.mydomain.com/?cjg_monitoring=1', $ip_add );
    if ( $content != "OK") $problem_encountered = true;
}

if ( !$problem_encountered ) echo "All IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses OK";
?>
```

in my case www.mydomain.com has many ip addresses of each version:

```
$host www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com has address 173.194.35.180
www.mydomain.com has address 173.194.35.176
www.mydomain.com has address 173.194.35.177
www.mydomain.com has IPv6 address 2001:db8:4016:801::1008
www.mydomain.com has IPv6 address 2001:db8:4016:801::1009
www.mydomain.com has IPv6 address 2001:db8:4016:801::1010
```

Which is why I use this :

```
  //return array[0][ip] or array[0][ipv6]
function get_all_ip_addresses( $url ){

    $url_tab = parse_url($url);
    $host = $url_tab['host']

    $ip4s = dns_get_record($host, DNS_A);
    $ip6s = dns_get_record($host, DNS_AAAA);

    return array_merge($ip4s, $ip6s);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the trick consists in replacing the hostname by its IP in the URL and at the same time adding a header with the hostname anyway

NB: `http://192.168.0.1/?var=1` becomes `http://[2001:db8::1]/?var=1` with ipv6

```
function file_get_contents_url_ip($url,$host_ip=null,$ip_version=0,$ignore_certificate=false) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    if (!is_null($host_ip)){
        $urldata = parse_url($url); 

        //  Ensure we have the query too, if there is any... 
        if (!empty($urldata['query'])) 
          $urldata['path'] .= "?".$urldata['query']; 

        //  Specify the host (name) we want to fetch...
        $headers = array("Host: ".$urldata['host']); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 

        //  create the connecting url (with the hostname replaced by IP) 
        if( $ip_version == 6 )
            $url = $urldata['scheme']."://[".$host_ip.']'.$urldata['path']; 
        else
            $url = $urldata['scheme']."://".$host_ip.$urldata['path'];

        //ssl certificate would fail because https://192.168.0.1 is used instead of hostname
        $ignore_certificate = 1;
    }

    if( $ip_version == 4 )
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
    elseif( $ip_version == 6 )
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6 );

    if( $ignore_certificate )
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    else
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to process the output of your `host` command, and call it all in PHP using `exec()`. The result will be an array of IP addresses, both IPv4 and IPv6 - you can use regex to determine which is is if you need to.

```
function get_all_ip_addresses($host){
    exec('host ' . $host . ' | awk \'/has (IPv6 )?address/ { if ($3 == "IPv6") print $5; else print $4; }\'', $ips);
    return $ips;
}
```

Dump of the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 173.194.35.180
    [1] => 173.194.35.176
    [2] => 173.194.35.177
    [3] => 2001:db8:4016:801::1008
    [4] => 2001:db8:4016:801::1009
    [5] => 2001:db8:4016:801::1010
)
```

Comment: thanks, but it's better to use dns_get_record($host, DNS_AAAA); I updated my question and changed to title

Comment: It´s just that I really dislike using exec(). I even disabled all similar functions on my web servers